# Can OpenSSL verify software integrity as GPG does?

Tags: shell, openssl, gnupg, verify

To download and install `foo`,
we may need to verify against `foo.asc`,
a "detached signature" file.
A script like

```
curl -O http://example.com/foo
curl -O https://example.com/foo.asc
gpg --verify foo.asc foo
```

requires `gpg` but could `openssl` do it?

Comment: No, because openssl does X.509, and gpg does PGP, and they aren't the same.

Comment: [joke] So you're downloading the signature file from HTTP (not HTTPS)? Tell me more about it.

Comment: [lol] Fixed in the example.

Answer (score 4):

> Can OpenSSL verify software integrity as GPG does?

It depends on the format and encoding. OpenSSL can handle messages and signatures in a number of formats and encodings, including PEM, DER, SMIME, PKCS7, PKCS12 and in some instances, MSBLOB.

In your case with a PGP signature, the answer is no. OpenSSL does not know how to parse the signature block:

```
$ cat openssl-1.0.1i.tar.gz.asc 
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Version: GnuPG v1

iQEcBAABAgAGBQJT4pu4AAoJENnE0m0OYESRle0H/A6fmNlUkhJ5NS5/W6HbztKE
j5xWzecv7HKElr01tleyGkefwg/whBhE1HN0QsFygOR29HFF4dhijjarYj7gh6tR
rsTGpbi+i0j2355a/BJdisXx9IESQLHeXxIAcGYEyWJKAUPzIHnIq/de+/IU9Luz
Ck5aNaB2epB8mAyqHD8tkyK52764ngATElsuz9/aSGBSgoNkLXa/3nDEink2ckaD
+fiBftKALEmJy+aaKp3E3PE3rQ02L0UK0hsO9DfOe0SZtFOd1nGF3Pb1DgGvum+R
RYUXuroGc6D126lK/ThhqZxBOWn+TYmm9g+P15r9nWOUvqvP1Bn2no0AvRvZH30=
=f6Uy
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

You can find many of the formats supported by OpenSSL in `<openssl src>/crypto/pem/pem.h`. PGP is *not* one of them:

```
#define PEM_STRING_X509_OLD "X509 CERTIFICATE"
#define PEM_STRING_X509     "CERTIFICATE"
#define PEM_STRING_X509_PAIR    "CERTIFICATE PAIR"
#define PEM_STRING_X509_TRUSTED "TRUSTED CERTIFICATE"
#define PEM_STRING_X509_REQ_OLD "NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST"
#define PEM_STRING_X509_REQ "CERTIFICATE REQUEST"
...
#define PEM_STRING_PKCS7    "PKCS7"
#define PEM_STRING_PKCS7_SIGNED "PKCS #7 SIGNED DATA"
...
```

---

Related on the [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com): [openssl verify signature](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8956/openssl-verify-signature).